# How do I run an SQL update query using a like statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to update a field in a table using an SQL update query where there is a like statement referencing a value in another table. They syntax unfortunately is not working.  Below is my code.   In short, I am trying to put a '1' in the field 'Query07ParolaChiave' in the table 'tblSearchEngine01' when the value located in table 'tblsearchengine07' is present in the field 'tblMasterListOfEventsNotes' located in the table 'tblSearchEngine01'.  I think my code is almost complete but there is a syntax issue which i cant find.

```
st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, tblSearchEngine07 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect = '1' WHERE ((([tblSearchEngine01].[tblMasterListOfEventsNotes]) Like " * " & [tblsearchengine07].[ParolaChiave] & " * "))"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you 2 solutions :

This one is using `EXISTS` functions, and will check for each row in `tblSearchEngine01` if there is a matching value in `tblsearchengine07`

```
UPDATE 
    tblSearchEngine01
SET 
    tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect = '1' 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM tblsearchengine07
            WHERE [tblSearchEngine01].[tblMasterListOfEventsNotes] Like '*' & [tblsearchengine07].[ParolaChiave] & '*')
```

This one is more performant because it uses `JOIN`

```
UPDATE 
    tblSearchEngine01 
    INNER JOIN tblsearchengine07 
        ON [tblSearchEngine01].[tblMasterListOfEventsNotes] Like '*' & [tblsearchengine07].[ParolaChiave] & '*'
SET 
    tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect = '1'
```

I read something like in *ADO/VBA, you have to use `%` instead of `*` as the wildcard.*

You can have more information on wildcard and `LIKE` comparator [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-using-wildcard-characters-in-microsoft-access-criteria-expressions/)

**UPDATE**

**Why the '1' after select in your first solution?**
`EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...` is better for performance because it return only the number 1 instead of fields, anyway EXISTS just stop the excecution after 1 element found.

**'Performant' means more consuming in regards to space and memory?**
JOIN is more performant in term of time of execution, RDBMS are far better at joining tables than using subquery, in some rare case, it's more interesting to use the 1st solution.

**Also, any initial thoughts as to why my original solution (coming straight from an Access Query which works) does not function?**
I cannot really know but perhaps it's because of `" * "`, because you are saying `SPACE + * + SPACE + VALUE + SPACE + * + SPACE`. For ex : `'John' LIKE '  John  '`

May be with `"*"` instead of `" * "` could solve it...

I have no other track, I'm not Access sql developper, I usually play around Sql server/Oracle/mySql, hope it helped. ;)

Comment: They both work great! Would you mind 3 clarification??  Why the '1' after select in your first solution?   'Performant' means more consuming in regards to space and memory?  Also, any initial thoughts as to why my original solution (coming straight from an Access Query which works) does not function?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your like this way:

```
... Like '*" & tblsearchengine07.parolachiave & "*'))"
```

Comment: Still not working :(    st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, tblSearchEngine07 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect = '1' WHERE ((([tblSearchEngine01].[tblMasterListOfEventsNotes]) Like  ' * " & [tblsearchengine07].[ParolaChiave] & " * ' ))"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

Answer (score 2):

The like statement go into the WHERE clause.

If you do want to use LIKE without you care about caps letters, then you can use it like this:

LIKE COLUMN_NAME = '%WhatYouLike%'

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

1. Use a table variable (@Table) with a unique/primary key coming from the table to be updated.
2. SELECT all the data to be updated (you can add the like statement here) and then INSERT that in the created table variable.
3. Construct the UPDATE statement with an INNER JOIN to the table variable matching with the unique/primary key.

I know this may take a lot of steps but believe me these are more efficient than using a black list approach.